# How can I resolve a compilation error when using a git dependency in Cargo with Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, build-dependencies, ripgrep

I am facing a compilation error after switching one of my dependencies from cargo.io to a GitHub using Cargo. I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.

Details:

- Language: Rust
- Package manager: Cargo
- Source Code: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep.git
- Change: Only Cargo.toml

Before:

```ini
....
[dependencies]
....
log = "0.4.5"
regex = "1.3.5"
serde_json = "1.0.23"
termcolor = "1.1.0"
....
```

After:

```ini
....
[dependencies]
....
log = "0.4.5"
regex = "1.3.5"
serde_json = "1.0.23"
termcolor = { git = "https://github.com/BurntSushi/termcolor.git", tag = "1.1.0" }
....
```

Build Log:

```
~/ripgrep# cargo build --release
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/BurntSushi/termcolor.git`
   Compiling ripgrep v13.0.0 (/root/ripgrep)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> crates/core/args.rs:304:39
    |
304 |             cli::stdout_buffered_line(color)
    |             ------------------------- ^^^^^ expected `termcolor::ColorChoice`, found `ColorChoice`
    |             |
    |             arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: `ColorChoice` and `termcolor::ColorChoice` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `ColorChoice` is defined in crate `termcolor`
   --> /opt/rust/git/checkouts/termcolor-0e1edd74bd062d15/1679b36/src/lib.rs:207:1
    |
207 | pub enum ColorChoice {

.....

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `ripgrep` (bin "rg") due to 19 previous errors
```

Some Tries:

- `cargo clean`
- switch tag to 1.2.0
- use rev = "a4c5d51"

Comment: You would need to `[patch]` the termcolor in so all dependents in the dependency graph will use that version. See linked Q&A.